# Why does my Network preference pane freeze every time I open it?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, performance, system-settings

For some time (about a month give or take) the Network Preferences pane in System Preferences has been freezing every time I open it.

Wi-Fi works fine and I can connect using the menubar icon, but I can't change anything in the Network preference pane. System Preferences also works fine, except for the Network preference pane.

When I open the Network preferences pane, the app freezes and starts eating up system resources.

[image]
[image]

I've used the Tracking-blocker Disconnects Mac App since August, but even with the service turned off and the program not running, the Network preference pane still freezes.

```
System info:
MacOS Sierra - 10.12.6 (16G29)
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
2,5 GHz Intel Core i7 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
```

Updates:
1 | I've tried booting into Safe Mode which hasn't solved the problem.
2 | I've done a hardware test, which produced no errors and didn't solve the problem.
3 | I've done a SMC reset which hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (hold `Shift` while booting) and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @Allan problem persists when booted into Safe Mode

Comment: That tells you that it's not a 3rd party app that's causing it.  The next thing I would try is installing a clean version of macOS on a USB stick/drive to see if the problem goes away.  I would also try running [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Comment: @Allan ran a hardware test last night, but it returned no errors. this is getting more and more mysterious!

Comment: Did  you do the clean install on the external USB?

Comment: @Allan No, I haven't tried that yet. Can you direct me to a guide on how to do it and test if it works?

Comment: See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135255/can-i-install-os-x-onto-a-separate-external-drive-partition

Comment: @Allan installed Sierra on an external drive and tested, and it worked without any problems. Could open the network panel fine and sub-option menus, so it must be something with my installation of MacOS?

Comment: That’s exactly what that means.  At this point I would be working on a strategy to reinstall. My suggestion is to back up with Time Machine, wipe the drive, do a clean install, apply updates, and migrate your *data only*. Manually install your Apps to ensue your not restoring something corrupt. Then, when everything is working, do a fresh backup

Comment: @Allan, thank you and goddammit! Guess I'll need to see if I can find a way to clear saved networks through terminal until I have time to wipe the computer then.

Comment: @Allan I found another way to solve it! Have your computer stolen and buy a new one. At least I know that one works.  Thank you for all your help though! 