# How do I delete a saved wifi network, when unable to use the Network panel/GUI in System pref?

Tags: terminal, network, macos, wifi, plist

I need to delete a saved public wifi network, which my computer keeps trying to connect to when I'm at home, but I can't open my Network preferences and do it trough the GUI, due to an error in my MacOS installation (see linked question below for details).

I'm guessing there might be a way to do it, through Terminal or digging into a .plist, but haven't been able to find any non-GUI guides to this through searching, so how can this be done?

[Why does my Network preference pane freeze every time I open it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310577/why-does-my-network-preference-pane-freeze-every-time-i-open-it?noredirect=1#comment400727_310577)

System info:
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the list of preferred networks with the command:

`sudo networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks en0`

You can then copy the name of the wifi you want to remove from the list and use the command (replacing `wifi_to_be_removed` with the name of the wifi):

`sudo networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork en0 wifi_to_be_removed`

Note: `en0` is usually the device name of the AirPort Wifi card in a mac that doesn't have an ethernet port (modern portable Macs). To be sure of the device name use the command:
 `sudo networksetup -listallhardwareports`
to list the various network devices and their denomination. This would vary for

Comment: Is there a place I can find other possible device names for my wifi card? When running `-listpreferredwirelessnetworks en1´ I get the error "en1 is not a Wi-Fi interface.
** Error: Error obtaining wireless information."

Comment: Just realised I hadn't added my device specs to this post, so have done that now, hopefully that helps.

Comment: `sudo networksetup -listallhardwareports` gives you the list of the devices

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: cool, I figured out by trial and error that it was en0, but good you updated it for others to find!

Comment: could also be `en0`, that's the case on a 2019 MBP at least.  but yes, `-listallhardwareports` shows that too, after I got `en1 is not a Wi-Fi interface.`.